# How to get records between from and to date, when dates are for the same month/year?

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a query to that can get some records in a table that is between a from and to date, with the dates being in month/year only. The problem that I am having is trying to get the records when the from and to dates are for the same month/year.

Here is a example of the issue that I am having:

```
select start_date 
from job
where trunc(start_date) between to_date('05-2016','mm-yyyy') and to_date('05-2016','mm-yyyy')
```

In the job table, there are records with start_date in the month of May, but in order to see them I need to set the to date to '06-2016'. Is there way to get all of the records with a start_date in the month of May by just specifying that the from and to dates is 05-2016?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not specifying the day of month? `between to_date('05-01-2016', 'mm-dd-yyyy') and to_date('05-31-2016', 'mm-dd-yyyy')` Is it because you don't know how to calculate the last day of month or because that date is supplied to you with month and year only?

Comment: Please specify Oracle Sql, preferably which version you are using (ie 10g)

Comment: Your code should work.  One problem is a time zone issue on `start_date`.  In other words your question does not have enough information for an answer.

Comment: i think it is a misunderstanding of the to dates in the between function.  They are both 5/1 in this case.  This would only select start_dates on 5/1

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you explain the time zone issue here?

Comment: @Lock . . . Some databases have date/time types that include time zones.  You can have a timezone mismatch between the constants and the dates in the database.  As I say, your question doesn't have enough information.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are selecting all `start_date`'s between 5/1/2016 and 5/1/2016.

It seems like you want to capture everything in a month, but you are not specifying a format to truncate.  Without specifying 'Month' in the `Trunc()` you are truncating to the day.  When you truncate to Month you can now, actually just set it equal to the `to_date()` rather than between:

```
select start_date 
from job
where trunc(start_date,'Month') = to_date('05-2016','mm-yyyy')
```

[Here is some information](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) on Trunc(date, [fmt]).  when the fmt argument is left blank Trunc() defaults to 'round' to the nearest day but there are many other options.

If you want to specify ranges greater than a Month you can use between (but note, this is from the first day of the first `to_date()` to the first day of the second 'to_date()':

```
select start_date 
from job
where trunc(start_date) 
between to_date('06-2016','mm-yyyy') 
and to_date('09-2016','mm-yyyy')
```

In this example all Start_dates would populate between 6/1/2016 and 9/1/2016.

I think the most accurate way to do this would be:

```
select start_date 
from job
where trunc(start_date) 
between to_date('06-01-2016','mm-dd-yyyy') 
and to_date('09-30-2016','mm-dd-yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
select start_date 
from job
where trunc(start_date, 'mm') between
        to_date('05-2016', 'mm-yyyy')
    and to_date('05-2016', 'mm-yyyy')
```

Oracle has no way of interpolating the date on the right end of your `between` as falling at the end of the month. When `to_date()` is missing a day value in the format it simply supplies the 1st as the default value. Not sure if that's the behavior your were anticipating.

If instead you truncate dates by month (rather than day) then the comparisons will only involve dates falling on the first of the month. With the dates collapsed that way you can then treat a start and end of the two identical values as an inclusive range. Presumably you'll replace the hard-coded dates with parameters of some form and this works for wider ranges as well. Of course, the `between` can be just an equality test if you're *always* querying on a single month. And this isn't going to use an index on your column so it's not necessarily the most efficient.

I think this is what you're looking for. Is there a reason you need to supply the date value(s) in that format? Perhaps there's a better way to approach this using a little date math.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
select start_date 
from job
where trunc(start_date) between to_date('05-2016','mm-yyyy')
and dateadd('d', -1, dateadd('m', 1, to_date('05-2016','mm-yyyy')))
```

In order to see an entire month worth of dates, your date range in the `between` clause must be a full month long.

Comment: The idea is sound. But the `between` is going to include one too many months. You need strictly less than.

Comment: @shawnt00, I have edited my answer to address that problem.